# Calling next method if there's no result from previous method

Tags: java, methods, option-type

I have a block of code where I call methodTwo if methodOne returns null. If methodTwo returns null, I call methodThree

```
Optional<Workflow> optionalWorkflow = remoteWorkflowProvider.getWorkflow(request);

if (!optionalWorkflow.isPresent()) {
  log.info("Cannot find workflow using remoteWorkflowProvider");
  optionalWorkflow = featureBasedWorkflowProvider.getWorkflow(request);
}

if (!optionalWorkflow.isPresent()) {
  log.info("Cannot find workflow using featureBasedWorkflowProvider");
  optionalWorkflow = legacyWorkflowProvider.getWorkflow(request);
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: You could put together a list of providers, and then loop through them and break if `optionalWorkflow.isPresent()`

Comment: [`first().or(() -> second()).or(() -> third())`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#or-java.util.function.Supplier-)

Comment: @Michael admirable choice not answering considering the current trend. I'd offer you a coffee.

Answer (score -1):

`Optional` has some really powerful tools that don't rely on `if-then-else` flows. Look up the `Optional.orElse` function for instance to clean up your code a bit:

```
optionalWorkflow.orElse(featureBasedWorkflowProvider.getWorkflow(request))
```

You can also use `orElseGet` to return a lambda which gives you more functionality:

```
optionalWorkflow.orElseGet((value) -> {
   log.info("Cannot find workflow using remoteWorkflowProvider");
   return featureBasedWorkflowProvider.getWorkflow(request));
});
```

Comment: `orElse` also requires a `T`, not a `Supplier<Optional<T>>`. Why should this typecheck?